# PHP is returning error 504 (excessive load of async calls?)

Tags: php, node.js

I'm running php and nodejs. I run some code in php and since I want the next code to be async without resorting to threading I send the information to nodejs and nodejs makes a new call to php. This works perfectly.
However, **the code to run async has to sleep** and might occurr per logged in user - as to say: it will be run **a lot**. I noticed that when running only ONE single task regarding that script and trying to access index.php at the same time, the browser query to the server was put on hold indefinitely (loading, loading, loading, ...) and lastly crashed with a 504 served. My question here being: **maintaining** the algorithm I designed, is there any tweak I should do regarding max_time_out in relation to sleep? Or should I just "sleep" in nodejs and send the data to PHP? Tyvm, will provide more detail if needed...

Comment: More detail would be good, it may even stop people voting to close this question

Comment: @RiggsFolly hello Riggs, but what exactly? I use regular http localhost requests to talk between node and php... I don't know exactly what I could add to turn the problem more clearer, it is basically this...

Comment: Try running that test above, but use 2 different client PC's so you are connecting from 2 different ip's. Or even 2 different Browsers on the same client PC. See if you still get a 504.

Comment: I have to say that any process that involves it _going to sleep for 5 minites_ should probably be looked at again **very closely**. There has to be a better way of doing it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have to simulate human behaviour, so there's that. Therefore the reason I'm asking whether doing it in nodejs would be better... I'll try different systems and let you know

Comment: Interesting, got a little more info? Is this wait happening to a browser page? What is supposed to happen when the script wakes up?